# How do i define a generic constructor in dll with cpp?

Tags: c++

Im getting an error:

> ```
> Unresolved external symbol \__declspec(dllimport) public: \__cdecl Foo\<long\>::Foo\<Long\>(void) ...
> ```

The code:

```
///Foo.h
#pragma once

template<typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    __declspec(dllexport) Foo();
}

///Foo.cpp
template<typename T> Foo<T>::Foo() {
    // ...
}


///main.cpp
#include "Foo.h"

int main(void) {
    Foo<long> longfoo;
}
```

I would like to have a generic constructor, so I don't have to define it for every type separately; ie:

```
Foo<long>::Foo() {}
Foo<int>::Foo() {}
Foo<Foo<long>>::Foo() {}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: You can't.  Templates get stamped out at compile time, they don't exist at run time.  You would have to manually instantiate all of the templates for all of the types you want so they get stamped out before being turned into a DLL